# Как сделать форму оформления заказа в WooCommerce динамической?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: На странице  **Оформление заказа** в разделе ***Оплата и доставка*** необходимо сделать форму таким образом, что бы в зависимости от способа доставки подгружались дополнительные элементы. В блоке ***Оплата и доставка*** Есть 4 видо доставки (**Почта России**, **Транспортная Компания**, **Пункт выдачи** и **Доставка до двери**). Нужно чтобы при выборе одного из этих способов подгружались некоторые элементы. К примеру: Выбираем **Пункт выдачи** и подгружаются адреса откуда можно забрать товар. Выбираем **Почта Росси** и появляется форма для заполнения адреса и так далее. Подскажите как это реализовать? Может плагины есть? Я пробовал плагин Saphali, но он не подошел. Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для всех ваших методов доставки нужно создавать классы наследуя `WC_Shipping_Method`. И там добавляете нужные поля на фронт и в админку для настроек. Код большой, поэтому вот ссылку на доку: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shipping-method-api/

После регистрации методов доставки добавить поля на фрон

```
class Checkout {
    /**
     * Add hooks
     */
    public function hooks() {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', [ $this, 'fields' ] );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', [ $this, 'validate' ] );
    }

    /**
     * Fields
     *
     * @param WC_Shipping_Rate $shipping_rate Shipping rate.
     */
    public function fields( WC_Shipping_Rate $shipping_rate ) {
        // The same hook work on cart page.
        if ( ! is_checkout() ) {
            return;
        }
        $shipping_method = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'shipping_method', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY );
        $shipping_method = isset( $shipping_method[0] ) ? preg_replace( '/:[0-9]{1,10}$/', '', $shipping_method[0] ) : [];
        if ( 'your-shipping-method' === $shipping_method && 'your-shipping-method' === $shipping_rate->get_method_id() ) {
            // Your fields there.
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validate fields
     */
    public function validate() {
        $nonce = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'shipping_nova_poshta_for_woocommerce_nonce', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, Main::PLUGIN_SLUG . '-shipping' ) ) {
            return;
        }
        if ( notvalid ) { // Add your validation:
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Your error', 'your-domain' ), 'error' );
        }
    }

}
```